# How should I change the way I load my dataset so I can take advantage of kaggles TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, kaggle

I am using the Keras API of tensorflow train a model that can detect what characters of the Kannada language script are in an image, Kannada is a South Indian language that can have upwards of 657 classes for classification as characters are combinations of consonants and vowels. For further clarity, please refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_script) Wikipedia article.

The dataset for this model is a single directory with multiple subdirectories, each subdirectory corresponding to a class, like so: [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRR7w.png)

Alternately, you can see the structure more clearly if youvwisit the kaggle public link [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pranavshashidhara/kannada-images-with-noise).

Following are the imports that I make:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

I load the data using ImageDataGenerator as I can easily split the dataset into separate training and validation sets. below is the code that I use to construct these two sets:

```py
# Creating training and validation data generators
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.01)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(
directory="../input/kannada-images-with-noise/Images_with_noise",
subset="training",
batch_size=256,
shuffle=True,
classes=image_classes,
color_mode='grayscale',
target_size=(75,75))

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_directory(
directory="../input/kannada-images-with-noise/Images_with_noise",
subset="validation",
batch_size=256,
shuffle=True,
classes=image_classes,
color_mode='grayscale',
target_size=(75,75))

# Creating step sizes
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
```

I then just pass these generators to the model.fit() function like so

```py
# Training our model
model.fit(
    x=train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, 
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
    epochs=25,
    verbose=1
)
```

I have stuck with this method so far as it is straightforward and easy. However, if I want to make use of the TPU available on kaggle, I will have to change the way I load my data and use tf.data.Dataset as ImageDataGenerator cannot take the the Google Cloud Service link of the kaggle dataset to fetch the data.

How do I use tf.data.Dataset to load in my data? I would really appreciate if you can point link any examples or tutorials that I can follow. If it is better for me to change the way my directories are structured, please tell me how I must do so.

Comment: do you have the data on google cloud?

Comment: No, the data is on kaggle as a public dataset, but I think kaggle uses GCS to store public datasets. I have put a link to the dataset my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that i know
Note that the tpu argument to TPUClusterResolver is a special address just for Colab. In the case that you are running on Google Compute Engine (GCE), you should instead pass in the name of your CloudTPU.

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.240.1.74:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.240.1.74:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
All devices:  [LogicalDevice(name='/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7', device_type
```

Manual device placement
After the TPU is initialized, you can use manual device placement to place the computation on a single TPU device.

```
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
with tf.device('/TPU:0'):
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print("c device: ", c.device)
print(c)
```

```
c device:  /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
```

Most times users want to run the model on multiple TPUs in a data parallel way. A distribution strategy is an abstraction that can be used to drive models on CPU, GPUs or TPUs. Simply swap out the distribution strategy and the model will run on the given device.

```
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
```

To replicate a computation so it can run in all TPU cores, you can simply pass it to strategy.run API. Below is an example that all the cores will obtain the same inputs (a, b), and do the matmul on each core independently. The outputs will be the values from all the replicas.

```
@tf.function
def matmul_fn(x, y):
  z = tf.matmul(x, y)
  return z

z = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(a, b))
print(z)
```

```
PerReplica:{
  0: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  1: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  2: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  3: tf.Tensor(
[[22. 28.]
 [49. 64.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32),
  4: tf.Tensor(
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I am aware as to how I should initialize and setup the TPU that kaggle provides by following their documentation. My problem was that I could not figure out how to change the way I load my data, i.e how I should change my code from using ImageDataGenerator to using tf.data.Dataset to import and organize my data to be used in model.fit() function as there isn't any way to use ImageDataGenerator with TPU's.